# How to group related fields in JSONL?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, shopify

I am using Shopify's bulk operation mutation in GraphQL to fetch bulk data for products, invoices, transactions etc.

Shopify returns this data as JSONL. Each line is an object and if it is related to another item then it will have a `__parentid` which can be used to figure out its parent.

For example, the returned data will look something like this:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: "1",
    __typename: "parent"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    __parentId: "1",
    __typename: "child"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    __parentId: "2",
    __typename: "grandChild"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    __parentId: "2",
    __typename: "grandChild"
  }
]
```

In order to save this in my database, I need to nest each child value within its parent.

So the above would become

```
[
  {
    id: "1",
    __typename: "parent",
    child: [
      {
        id: "2",
        __parentId: "1",
        __typename: "child",
        grandChild: [
          {
            id: "3",
            __parentId: "2",
            __typename: "grandChild"
          },
          {
            id: "4",
            __parentId: "2",
            __typename: "grandChild"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

This is one approach I tried where you can see I am trying to attach the children to the parent object and then once it has been moved, delete the original object.

```
export const reduceBulkResult = (chunks) => {
  chunks.reverse()

  chunks.forEach(chunk => {

    const parent = chunks.find(node =>{
      return node.id === chunk.__parentId
    })

    if( parent ) {

      if( parent[chunk.__typename] ) {
        parent[chunk.__typename].push(chunk)
      } else {
        parent[chunk.__typename] = [chunk]
      }
      
    }

  })

  return chunks;
}

console.log("reduceBulkResult", reduceBulkResult(data)) 
[
    {
        "__parentId": "2",
        "__typename": "grandChild",
        "id": "4"
    },
    {
        "__parentId": "2",
        "__typename": "grandChild",
        "id": "3"
    },
    {
        "__parentId": "1",
        "__typename": "child",
        "grandChild": [
            {
                "__parentId": "2",
                "__typename": "grandChild",
                "id": "4"
            },
            {
                "__parentId": "2",
                "__typename": "grandChild",
                "id": "3"
            }
        ],
        "id": "2"
    },
    {
        "__typename": "parent",
        "child": [
            {
                "__parentId": "1",
                "__typename": "child",
                "grandChild": [
                    {
                        "__parentId": "2",
                        "__typename": "grandChild",
                        "id": "4"
                    },
                    {
                        "__parentId": "2",
                        "__typename": "grandChild",
                        "id": "3"
                    }
                ],
                "id": "2"
            }
        ],
        "id": "1"
    }
]
```

As you can see, there is a lof of duplication here and I need to get rid of the original objects some how and just keep the parent objects which have all the nested data.

I feel like I'm missing a trick here. There must be an easier way.

Shopify have some good tips such as[Reading the JSONL file in reverse makes it easier to group child nodes](https://shopify.dev/api/usage/bulk-operations/queries#read-the-jsonl-file-in-reverse)

Comment: Is that max 3 level, parent, child, grandchild? As you have different child key name such as `variant` and `childVariant`.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Have updated it. It can go more than 3 levels. I believe there is no limit as to how many levels it may be nested as it is data returned from Shopify and their graphql schema is very deep

Comment: Also, each item only max one child? What if there are two children with the same parent?

Comment: There can be many children for each parent

Comment: Can you please show how to represent the data if there are two children for one single parent?

Comment: Sure thing. I realised the children values should be arrays (not objects). I have updated the example above to reflect this and show how it would look with multiple children

Answer (score 1):

I get the parent with filter() and then use recursive in `getChildren` to get the result.

I cannot find a simple way and you may change codes to make it more simple.

```js
const data = [ { id: "1", __typename: "parent", }, { id: "2", __parentId: "1", __typename: "child", }, { id: "3", __parentId: "2", __typename: "grandChild", }, { id: "4", __parentId: "2", __typename: "grandChild", }, ]; const o = [ { id: "1", __typename: "parent", child: [ { id: "2", __parentId: "1", __typename: "child", grandChild: [ { id: "3", __parentId: "2", __typename: "grandChild", }, { id: "4", __parentId: "2", __typename: "grandChild", }, ], }, ], }, ];

const convert = data => {
  const parent = data.filter(el => !el.__parentId);

  const getChildren = (data, parentId) => {
    let store = {};
    for (const obj of data) {
      if (obj.__parentId === parentId) {
        const children = data.reduce((a, b) => {
          if (b.__parentId === obj.id) {
            if (a[b.__typename]) {
              a[b.__typename].push({ ...b, ...getChildren(data, b.id) });
            } else {
              a[b.__typename] = [{ ...b, ...getChildren(data, b.id) }];
            }
          }
          return a;
        }, {});
        store = { ...store, ...obj, ...children };
      }
    }
    return store;
  };

  return parent.map(el => {
    const children = data.reduce((a, b) => {
      if (b.__parentId === el.id) {
        if (a[b.__typename]) {
          a[b.__typename].push({ ...b, ...getChildren(data, el.id) });
        } else {
          a[b.__typename] = [{ ...b, ...getChildren(data, el.id) }];
        }
      }
      return a;
    }, {});
    return { ...el, ...children };
  });
};

const output = convert(data);

console.log(output);
```